# Stop javascript from executing on page load and execute from ASP.NET codebehind

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

First; I'm trying to do two things in my ASP.NET / JavaScript code.

1) open a jQuery dialog from ASP.NET codebehind. (Works only when the javascript also executes on startup)

2) stop the same javascript/jQuery dialog as mention in 1) from showing on every pageload.

So the code below works great, but executes on page load which I try to stop. In addition this format (without function name) won't let me call the function from codebehind if I understand this [How can I prevent this jQuery function from being executed on every page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335308/how-can-i-prevent-this-jquery-function-from-being-executed-on-every-page-load) correctly:

```
$(function() {
        $( "#dialogConfirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:180,
            width: 500,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Delete": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

and this doesn't work (just shows the div on the page and not as a jQuery dialog):

```
$(function showConfirmDialog() {
        $( "#dialogConfirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:180,
            width: 500,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Delete": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

The only difference is the lack of function naming in the first. 
So, can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to just make a script that I can call from codebehind that won't execute on page load?

Comment: you could put it in a function and then from your code behind add some script to the page that calls the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your js function to this:

```
function ShowDialog() {
    $( "#dialogConfirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:180,
        width: 500,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Delete": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Then in your .cs file, put this in the Page_Load

```
if (IsCallback)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:ShowDialog();", true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you both for the interest. I get it to partly work with Kierans ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript approach. But the div still shows on the page before I call the javascript to display it as a dialog (then it disappears from the page, and displays as a dialog instead.

This is the HTML div in my aspx page:
`<div id="dialogConfirm" title="Delete?">
      <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
    </div>`

Comment: It's also relevant to mention that after running the js from codebehind once, all works great after that. The div doesn't re-appear on page after that.
Please also see screenshots here: http://imgur.com/gallery/tXugH

Comment: Fixed the last remaining "issue" I had by changing `<div id="dialogConfirm" title="Delete?" >` to `<div id="dialogConfirm" title="Delete?" style="display:none">`

Answer (score 1):

Add a function with a name like "showDialog" in your aspx page.

```
function showDialog(){
    $( "#dialogConfirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:180,
        width: 500,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Delete": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Then call it from your codebehind using the function name:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "", "showDialog", true);
```